# Error: The name or value attribute of @ConditionalOnProperty must be specified in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, gradle-eclipse

I'm using Spring Boot with Solr. When I configured on Pom maven, i received an exception unexpected:

pom:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- SOLR -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-solr.verion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- WEB -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.27</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!-- Hibernate 4 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.12.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
```

Application class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({SearchContext.class, WebContext.class })
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Log exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to load bean class: ; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: The name or value attribute of @ConditionalOnProperty must be specified
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:390)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:162)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:299)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
at com.totoroads.data.solr.showcase.Application.main(Application.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The name or value attribute of @ConditionalOnProperty must be specified
at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:385)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.getNames(OnPropertyCondition.java:101)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnPropertyCondition.java:55)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:44)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:92)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:187)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:433)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:387)
... 13 more
```

If I run with old version, everthing is fine, but when upgrading to 1.2.5 I have seen error above. How to fix this exception, thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the related issue opened on [GitHub Spring-boot issues list](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2285).

It seems that you need a newer version of Spring framework as explained on the [Spring Boot 1.2 Release Note](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.2-Release-Notes#spring-41):

> Spring Boot 1.2 requires Spring Framework 4.1.5 or later and is not
>   compatible with Spring Framework 4.0.

Comment: thanks @aUserHimselt: I'm checking version in your link about Spring boot..

Comment: Did it work? Accept the answer or post the output with this solution, so that others with similar issues can use it.

Comment: @hi aUserHimself: Yes It worked,I have update all to latest version 1.5.2. With each versions, API was changed so I have to update my code, anyway thank so much :)